# Converting the zoom level of all links in a PDF document

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a document in PDF format. The document consists of several chapters, sections, etc.
Within the text, there are references to other chapters or sections; for instance:

> - We will see in chapter 15 that ...
> - The notion of ..., mentioned in section 7.1, ...

The references are "links"; that is, when you click on them, it jumps to the corresponding text.

However, the links change the zoom level of the PDF to "Fit Page", as shown in the following dialog box (the screenshot is taken in Adobe Acrobat):

[image: link properties]

I don't like this behavior, and prefer that the zoom level does not change. To this end, there's an option called "Inherit Zoom".

The problem is that there are too many links in the document to change them manually. So, I want to somehow programmatically change the zoom level of all links in the PDF document to "Inherit Zoom".

Is this possible using iText or similar libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try [Docotic.Pdf Library](http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) for this. To accomplish your task following should be done:

1. Enumerate actions somehow.
2. Reset action zoom level to 0 (it means that zoom remains unchanged)

Reset action zoom level function is common and may look like this:

```
private static void resetActionZoom(PdfAction action)
{
    PdfGoToAction goToAction = action as PdfGoToAction;
    if (goToAction == null)
        return;

    // process only actions with FitPage zoom level
    if (goToAction.View.Zoom != PdfZoom.FitPage)
        return;

    goToAction.View.SetZoom(0); // now zoom will remain unchanged after click by link
}
```

Here is a sample that enumerates all actions in PDF document and reset zoom level for each:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument("path_to_your_file.pdf");
foreach (PdfAction action in pdf.Actions)
    resetActionZoom(action);

pdf.Save("UpdateAllActions.pdf");
```

Another (and more accurate) way is to enumerate all links on each page and update associated actions the same way:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument("path_to_your_file.pdf");
foreach (PdfPage page in pdf.Pages)
{
    foreach (PdfWidget widget in page.Widgets)
    {
        PdfActionArea actionArea = widget as PdfActionArea;
        if (actionArea == null)
            continue;

        resetActionZoom(actionArea.Action);
    }
}

pdf.Save("UpdatePageLinks.pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me why the second approach is "more accurate"?

Comment: Sure. When you modify all actions in the document you may change some actions that you don't want to change - actions associated with PDF controls (buttons, text fields, e.t.c.) or actions associated with outlines (bookmarks). If you enumerate only required objects with actions explicitly - you have 100% control of what will be changed. But probably in your case it is not very important so you can just go first way.

Answer (score 1):

Foxit reader
Preferences/Page Display
check "Forbid the change of the current Zoom factor during execution of "Go to Destination actions(these actions can be launched from bookmarks)"